# How to get the hyperlink of a class on UIWebview?

Tags: class, hyperlink, uiwebview

I can get the text of the class by this code:

```
[webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementsByClassName('normal fs16 bold c-red2')[0].innerHTML;"];
```

But I need also to get the link of this class.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved getting all links of the website and working with the string:

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"var script = document.createElement('script');"
     "script.type = 'text/javascript';"
     "script.text = \"function getHyperlinks() { "
     "var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');"
     "var allLinks = '';"
     "for (var i = 0; i<links.length; i++) {"
     "var link = links[i].href + '~' + links[i].text + '~' + links[i].title + ';';"
     "allLinks += link;"
     "} return allLinks;"
     "}\";"
     "document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);"];


    NSString *html = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
                      @"getHyperlinks();"];
```